# c++ vector of pointers to functions with specific parameters

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, auto

if I have a function and I want to make a pointer to it with a specific parameter I can use auto but like this:

```
void bar(int n){std::cout << n;}
auto foo = std::bind(bar, 2);
```

but if I want to make a vector of these pointers it doesn't work

```
std::vector<auto> v;
```

Comment: You're not making a pointer to a function. You're creating a bind-expression. You cannot (easily) make a container of bind-expressions, but you *can* make a vector of `std::function<void()>`.

Comment: Do you know what `auto` means here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write `vector<decltype(foo)> v;` although that probably doesn't do what you want  (other `bind` expressions may give incompatible types).

As mentioned in comments, `std::function` is designed for this purpose:

```
std::vector< std::function<void()> > v;

v.emplace_back( foo );
v.emplace_back( std::bind(bar, 2) );
v.emplace_back( []{ std::cout << 2; } );
```